# $scope.apply not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im trying to learn Angular. 
Here is what im trying to do:

I am building an App that shows me citys. When i click on a city i want to see a list of all my favourite citys.

Using an "Show-List" Button with ng-click works but requires the button the be pushed.

Here is my approach for getting it done automatic:

**I want a list in my DOM automatically updated on change of the list.**

```
$scope.$watch('updatedList', function() {

        // CHECK IF WORKS
        console.log($scope.updatedList);

        // APPLY TO DOM
        $timeout(function(){

            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.watchList = $scope.updatedList;
            });

        }, 1000)
    });
```

The Console shows no error and gives out the correc values:

*Object {city.3: "Herat", city.7: "Haag", city.10: "Tilburg" ......}*

In my div is the following:

```
<ul>
                <li ng-repeat="y in updatedList">{{ y }}</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="a in watchList">{{ a }}</li>
            </ul>
```

First for the NG-Click-Version(which works on click) second for the $scope.$watch

Sorry for lots of questions but im really struggling with the Angular-Docs.

EDIT:

Function that Adds Citys to the List:

```
$scope.addToList = function(name,id) {

        var cityToAdd = name;
        var cityToAddID = id;

        // ADD A CITY TO THE COOKIE -> WORKS
        $cookies.put('city.' + cityToAddID, cityToAdd);
        $scope.newList = $cookies.getAll();
        $scope.addToListMessage = cityToAdd + " wurde hinzugefügt";

        // Show short INFONOTICE
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.addToListMessage = "";

            });
        }, 1000);
            // Update the List
            $scope.updateList();

    };
```

Second Functions -> gets Values from Cookies and puts them to an Array:

```
$scope.updateList = function() {

        var allCitys = $cookies.getAll();


        // PUT ALL INTO AN ARRAY -> WORKS
        var favouritesFromCookie = [];
        $.each(allCitys, function(index, value) {

            if (index.indexOf('city.') == 0) { favouritesFromCookie.push(value) }
        });

        // PUT THE ARRAY OF CITYS INTO A SCOPE_VARIABLE

            $scope.updatedList = favouritesFromCookie;



    };
```

Comment: This would me more clear if you included more of your code.  Where is the list of cities coming from?  Are you getting this from an http request?  A little more info would help out here.

Comment: don't need `$.apply()` inside `$timeout()` as it will call `$.apply()` internally. What changes `newList`? That's the part need to focus on

Comment: Okay, i will add the code in a second...

Comment: Also seems like a mismatch in your $watch . You are watching `newList` and updating `watchList ` with `updatedList`. More code and a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) would help (even if it's not working)

Comment: Thanks charlie, it was a mistake when trying to fix it. Im now watching updatedList. Ill try to upload it in plunker asap.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you get rid of $cookies. Get your app working a bit more without them. You shouldn't need any of the `$watch` you are using. Also, cookies are very limited in size and not a good storage mechnism for what you appear to be doing. localStorage would be far more appropriate

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, working with localStorage is next on my list. How can I update DOM on change without watch?

Comment: By keeping the same arrays not reassigning them constantly. Use `push()` to add to array. The way you are working directly from cookies is all backwards and is grossly overcomplicating things

Comment: Just tried that. Works. And i feel pretty stupid for overcomplicating this whole thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your $scope.updatedList needs to be an array to be used in ng-repeat.

Comment: updatedList is already an array, perhaps you are confusing it with updateList which is a function?

Comment: Well it is and it works on ng-click. Just doesnt work automatic. The array is made in "favouritesFromCookies".

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't directly write a list in expression. Try this

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="y in watchList">{{ y.city }}</li>
    <li ng-repeat="y in watchList">{{ y.yourListItem}}</li>
</ul>
```